# post form data with angular 2 to jee json web service

Tags: web-services, angular, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am trying to post my form data using Http post method in Angular 2 and receive that data in Java EE back end web service so this is my code for `UserComponent`:

```ts
  export class UserComponent{
  form : FormGroup;
  output: string ;
  public pro: Client[]=[];
 constructor(private http: Http,public fb: FormBuilder,private ClientService: ClientService) {
this.form=this.fb.group({
  userName : '',
  password : '',
  nom : '',
  email : '',
  phone : '',
  adress : '',

});
```

}

This is my template code for `UserComponent`:

```html
<md-card>
<form [formGroup]="form" class="form-group">
<md-input placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"></md-input><br>
<md-input placeholder="userEmail" formControlName="email"></md-input><br>
  <md-input placeholder="userPhone" formControlName="phone"></md-input><br>
<md-input placeholder="username" formControlName="userName"></md-input><br>
<md-input placeholder="shippingAddress" formControlName="adress"></md-input><br>
<md-input placeholder="password" formControlName="password"></md-input><br>
</form>
```

```
<md-card>
<button (click)="onSubmit(form.value);" md-raised-button ">Create User</button>
</md-card>
```

for the `userService`:

```ts
  sendInfo(value){
const body = new URLSearchParams(value);
body.set('Email', value.email);
body.set('name', value.name);
body.set('Address', value.adress);
body.set('Phone', value.phone);
body.set('password', value.password);
body.set('username', value.userName);

let headers = new Headers();
//headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/BCWEB/AddUser',body.toString(), {
  headers : headers
}).map(res => res.json());
```

}

Now for the backend Java EE web service:

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/AjouterClient")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void post(
        @FormParam(value="Clientnom")String nom ,
        @FormParam(value="ClientEmail")String email,
        @FormParam(value="ClientPhone")String tel ,
        @FormParam(value="username")String adress ,
        @FormParam(value="password")String username ,
        @FormParam(value="shippingAddress")String password) {

     metier.ajouterClient(new     Client(nom,email,tel,username,password,adress));

       }
```

Comment: And what's your question? SO isn't a tutorial service; if there's a problem with what you've shown, give a [mcve] that explains what it is.

Comment: my probelm is that data of the form dosent get send to the server

Comment: are you subscribing to the request in your component?

Comment: thank you  AJT_82   so mucchhhhhh  ive solved it

Comment: You are welcome, I had a feeling that could be the issue! :P Have a great end of the weekend and happy coding :)